# How to use nelmio/api-doc-bundle standalone (without symfony app)?

Tags: php, nelmioapidocbundle

My web application is not based on Symfony or any other open-source framework.

How can I still use the package nelmio/api-doc-bundle to generate my API documentation from class annotations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**nelmio-api-doc** bundle  is made symfony platform only so you can not use it without symfony.

if you want to use only API documentation then https://swagger.io/swagger-ui/ may help you. swagger provides ymal and json (annotations is also part of symfony) based documentation and its implement most of popular work platform.

actually nelmio-api-doc bundle is using swagger-ui as API documentation provider (in config setting https://github.com/nelmio/NelmioApiDocBundle)